Can anyone explain why the Nautilus (file explorer) seems to be extremely slow at times? (includes videos)
Here's a video of folders taking a long time to load -- (display the folders and files) after clicking them in Nautilus.

Keep in mind that this on a machine with:

32GiB RAM
AMD Ryzen™ 7 9700X × 16
1 TB m.2 drive with mainboard PCIe 5.0 x4 m.2
Advanced Thermal Design & M.2 Thermal Guard ：To Ensure VRM Power Stability & 25110 M.2 SSD Performance

Running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS & Gnome 42, running XOrg (not Wayland).
$ /usr/bin/nautilus --version
$ GNOME nautilus 46.2


No other disk I/O of any consequence going on during this time -- no other apps running.
CPU utilization is very low at this time also

Here's the "Normal" fast load I see on those same folders:

Additional Odd Functionality
Now (days later) in Nautilus I'm seeing the "slowness" and I'm seeing this very odd issue where the Pictures folder is always highlighted (in orange).
In the next picture, you can see that the folder that has focus is the Downloads folder but the Pictures folder is still highlighted.
Why is that?

Resolution Of Odd Highlight : The only way I could finally resolve the issue with the highlighting was to kill Nautilus from the System Monitor.
That also cleared up the slowness, which seems to indicate that these issues are related to Nautilus.

Are you using xorg (vs Wayland)? Does it get faster after a bit? See bug 2042301. Might be another symptom.

@ubfan1 Ah, I should've mentioned that, I'm running XOrg.  I'll add it to the question.

There's no way to tell without profiling. Go to gnome discourse and ask how to profile Files.

@KhalidAbuShawarib thanks for the link, I will check it out.
